# Ruby: how to test against an exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby, I would like to write a spec against logger expection using allow. Please help, thank you.

Current spec

```
    it 'raises exception fetching auditables' do
  allow(NightLiaison::HttpConnection.open).to receive(:get).and_raise(StandardError)
  expect { described_class.fetch_auditables }.to raise_error('Fetching auditables raised an exception')
end
```

end

Method:

```
    def self.fetch_auditables
    HttpConnection.open.get AppConfig.api.nightliaison.fetch_auditables
     rescue => e
        LOGGER.error('Fetching auditables raised an exception', exception: e)
        Faraday::Response.new
      end
```

Error Message:

```
got #<WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET h... => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

Comment: Because you have enabled WebMock in your tests *all* attempts to make a network connection cause the `WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError` From what you posted I would have assumed that the `NightLiaison::HttpConnection.open` is properly mocked but maybe it's not?

Comment: Your are right Nightliason::HttpConnection.open is not mock in spec. Do I need to create a webmock stub request?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it fails when it tries `open` - if you mock that too, it could work. Try something like:

```
it 'raises exception fetching auditables' do
  open_mock = double
  allow(open_mock).to receive(:get).and_raise(StandardError)
  allow(NightLiaison::HttpConnection).to receive(:open).and_return(open_mock)
  expect { described_class.fetch_auditables }.to raise_error('Fetching auditables raised an exception')
end
```

Comment: I appreciate help, I'm getting different error at exception level "but nothing was raised"

Comment: So now you need to figure out why your code is failing this test ;)

Comment: I have feeling code issue, I need to do further debugging :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
allow(NightLiaison::HttpConnection).to receive_message_chain(:open, :get) { raise StandardError }
```